# Running command on Android from host

Tags: command-line, terminal, shell, android, shell-script

In order to optimize my work, I want to run commands from my host machine terminal. For example:

```
adb shell sh /data/local/tmp/check_freq.sh
```

The above command runs fine, but some of the commands need root permissions. If I do:

```
adb shell su
adb shell sh /data/local/tmp/check_freq.sh
```

then it returns the adb rooted terminal after the first command and I can't execute the command from host machine anymore.

What can be done to solve this?

Comment: i'm no expert, but is your device "rooted"?  There may be a whole process you need to do to get root access on your phone.   I don't know how much of it is necessary but people tend to do a whole process and part of it involves wiping the whole phone too! And booting the phone up with a new boot loader and writing a new image of an OS to the phone. And to start with "unlocking" the phone so as to be able to install the new boot loader. so as to write the image on bootup. Have you looked up how to root your particular model of phone and done that?

Comment: and what if you try `adb shell<ENTER>`  and then you try the commands, then you might be able to do mroe than one command?`

Comment: @barlop I have rooted phone. The reason I want to run script from host is because if my script is running from adb shell and my system restarts, it won't start on it's own. But if my script is being run from host, I can simply use adb wait-for-device to check it's availability and continue running the script.

Comment: doesn't android linux have its equivalent of what DOS had - autoexec.bat   I don't know if different distros of linux use a different one but  I have hacker keyboard and terminal emulator app. I see on my phone after doing `su<ENTER>` `ls /etc/init<tab>`  I see some files that might be for putting commands to run on startup.  .If your script knows how far it progressed and whether it completed or not,  then next time it restarts it can resume.  The file I see is `/etc/init.goldfish.sh` maybe that's it

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for the above scenario. If you want to run your command with sudo permissions from host on android device, then run following command

```
adb shell "su -c ***your_command***"
```

For example:

```
adb shell "su -c sh /data/local/tmp/check_freq.sh"
```